# Unable to push flask app to heroku, error with "Invalid URL './wheelhouse': No schema supplied."

Tags: python, heroku, flask, pip

I'm trying to push a flask app onto Heroku, but I keep getting this error that I have no idea how to fix:

```
remote:   Exception:
remote:   Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/basecommand.py", line 246, in main
remote:       status = self.run(options, args)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
remote:       requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 345, in prepare_files
remote:       functools.partial(self._prepare_file, finder))
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 290, in _walk_req_to_install
remote:       more_reqs = handler(req_to_install)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_set.py", line 467, in _prepare_file
remote:       req_to_install.populate_link(finder, self.upgrade)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/req/req_install.py", line 251, in populate_link
remote:       self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/index.py", line 425, in find_requirement
remote:       all_versions = self._find_all_versions(req.name)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/index.py", line 378, in _find_all_versions
remote:       for page in self._get_pages(locations, project_name):
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/index.py", line 579, in _get_pages
remote:       page = self._get_page(location)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/index.py", line 789, in _get_page
remote:       return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/index.py", line 878, in get_page
remote:       "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 476, in get
remote:       return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/download.py", line 367, in request
remote:       return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 450, in request
remote:       prep = self.prepare_request(req)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/sessions.py", line 381, in prepare_request
remote:       hooks=merge_hooks(request.hooks, self.hooks),
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 304, in prepare
remote:       self.prepare_url(url, params)
remote:     File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pip-6.1.1-py3.4.egg/pip/_vendor/requests/models.py", line 361, in prepare_url
remote:       "Perhaps you meant http://{0}?".format(url))
remote:   pip._vendor.requests.exceptions.MissingSchema: Invalid URL './wheelhouse': No schema supplied. Perhaps you meant http://./wheelhouse?
```

I also get this, even after I tried upgrading pip multiple times:

> You are using pip version 6.1.1, however version 8.0.3 is available.

Any suggestions on what to do?

Comment: could you show a part of your application, where route ```./wheelhouse``` defined?

Comment: Thats the thing, i have no idea where /app/.heroku/python is. I dont even have pip 6.1.1 on my system.

Comment: Is there any code, that you've wrote? You need to provide more information for this question. Like your project layout and code samples.

Comment: I basically followed this: http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-i-hello-world . Im not really sure what code to show since i dont even know where the files in the error actually are